# GRPC - Do I need to dispose or close the IService when I finish using it?

Tags: c#, grpc, grpc-dotnet

```
IService service = MyGrpcChannel.CreateGrpcService<IService>();
long[] ids = service.GetIds();
```

Do I need to do something to close/destroy the **IService** when I finish to use it?

Comment: Is it an `IDisposable`? Then use the `using` statement and never worry about manually disposing the resources yourself.

Comment: Better yet, use dependency injection.

Comment: It's not, I could make it IDisposable, but I don't know if it's necessary, because I don't know if the service needs to be disposed at all...

Comment: If you have resources you need to release or dispose manually, then yes make it `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary, the service is a thin veneer on the channel:

https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/issues/166

I also made a test creating 1 million services:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++)
{
    MyGrpcChannel.CreateGrpcService<IService>().GetIds();
}
```

No memory leak on the task manager. At the start of execution it was using 100mb and at the end too.